# Google BigQuery, Exception thrown for null value in prepared statement

Tags: jdbc, google-bigquery, prepared-statement

We are trying to load data to google bigquery using Jdbc (Simba driver).  When trying to insert a null value in a prepared statement, we are getting an exception.  This works when it is not a prepared statement.  For example, the code (with the connection Url hidden):

```
import java.sql.*;

public class Program {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Program program = new Program();
        try {
            program.doStatement();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {
            program.doPreparedStatement();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

   

    public Program() {}

    public void doPreparedStatement() throws Exception {
         try(Connection connection = getConnection()) {
            
            PreparedStatement statement = connection.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO test1.my_table (CONTACT, COMPANY, ADDRESS, CITY, STATE, ZIP) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?)");
            statement.setString(1, "MyContact");
            statement.setString(2, "MyCompany");
            statement.setString(3, "MyAddress");
            statement.setString(4, "MyCity");
            statement.setString(5, "MyState");
            statement.setNull(6, Types.BIGINT);
            System.err.println("Executing prepared statement...");
           int count = statement.executeUpdate();
        }
        System.err.println(" done.");
    }

    public void doStatement() throws Exception {
        try(Connection connection = getConnection()) {
            String create_command = 
                "CREATE TABLE test1.my_table ( CONTACT STRING, COMPANY STRING, ADDRESS STRING, CITY STRING, STATE STRING, ZIP STRING )";
            Statement createStatement = connection.createStatement( );
            System.err.println("Create table.");
            createStatement.execute(create_command);
            System.err.println("Table created.");
            
            System.err.println("Executing statement...");
            Statement statement = connection.createStatement();
            int count = statement.executeUpdate("INSERT INTO test1.my_table (CONTACT, COMPANY, ADDRESS, CITY, STATE, ZIP) VALUES ('MyContact','MyCompany','MyAddress','MyCity','MyState',NULL)");
        }
        System.err.println(" done.");
    }

    private Connection getConnection() throws Exception
    {
        Connection connection = null;
        connection = DriverManager.getConnection(CONNECTION_URL);
        return connection;
    }


}
```

Produces the following output:

```
SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.

Create table.

Table created.

Executing statement...

 done.

Executing prepared statement...

java.sql.SQLException: [Simba][BigQueryJDBCDriver](100032) Error executing query job. Message: Unparseable query parameter `` in type `TYPE_INT64`, Bad int64 value: null value: 'null'
        at com.simba.googlebigquery.googlebigquery.client.BQClient.insertJob(Unknown Source)
        at com.simba.googlebigquery.googlebigquery.client.BQClient.executeQuery(Unknown Source)
        at com.simba.googlebigquery.googlebigquery.dataengine.BQAbstractExecutor.execute(Unknown Source)
        at com.simba.googlebigquery.googlebigquery.dataengine.BQSQLExecutor.execute(Unknown Source)
        at com.simba.googlebigquery.jdbc.common.SPreparedStatement.executeWithParams(Unknown Source)
        at com.simba.googlebigquery.jdbc.common.SPreparedStatement.executeAnyUpdate(Unknown Source)
        at com.simba.googlebigquery.jdbc.common.SPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(Unknown Source)
        at Program.doPreparedStatement(Program.java:35)
Caused by: com.simba.googlebigquery.support.exceptions.GeneralException: [Simba][BigQueryJDBCDriver](100032) Error executing query job. Message: Unparseable query parameter `` in type `TYPE_INT64`, Bad int64 value: null value: 'null'
        ... 8 more
```

Answer (score 1):

I've found this to work when adding BigQuery support to [jOOQ](https://www.jooq.org) (see e.g. [#11841](https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/11841)), for numeric types:

```java
statement.setBigDecimal(6, null);
```

The `BigDecimal` type is the only numeric JDBC type that is not primitive. For other data types, use their respective setter if it is supported, or `setString(6, null)`, if Simba still doesn't like `NULL` values for the respective type, including e.g.:

- `Boolean`
- `Date`
- `Time`

If in doubt about any conversion problems (e.g. because Simba seems to bind `BigDecimal` as `STRING`, currently, at least in version 1.2.13.1016), make sure you cast the bind variable, e.g.:

```sql
CAST(? AS INT64)
```